# tinymce nanospell showing incorrect suggestion

Tags: php, plugins, tinymce

The tinymce plugin nano spell showing UNliscenced version as suggestion as shown in image 
 [Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfnDv.png)

When writing ffight or ttest and many different incorrect spellings it shows similar suggest as shown in image

Comment: have you got the solution?

Comment: @FaisalAhsan You could remove option menu so it shows blank except these options when those words are searched or else you had to purchase liscenced version.I searched a lot about it.Found none solution except this.So if ffight is typed the options will be blank menu on right click .This issue arises for some kyewords only .In plugin file remove thos e two menu.